# Fetch unique combinations of two field values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Probably it has been asked before but I cannot find an answer.

Table Data has two columns:

```
Source   Dest
1         2
1         2
2         1
3         1
```

I trying to come up with a MS Access 2003 SQL query that will return:

```
1       2
3       1
```

But all to no avail. Please help!

UPDATE: exactly, I'm trying to exclude 2,1 because 1,2 already included. I need only unique combinations where sequence doesn't matter.

Comment: 2 - 1 Is unique as well, should it be excluded?

Comment: Why would 2,1 be left out? Is it beacuase 1,2 is included? And how then do you decide which to use 1,2 or 2,1?

Comment: 2,1 should be excluded, that's the problem

Comment: astander, it doesn't matter whether 1,2 or 2,1 is included as long as it's only one of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ms Access you can try

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        *
FROM Table1 tM
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t WHERE tM.Source = t.Dest AND tM.Dest = t.Source AND tm.Source > t.Source)
```

**EDIT:**

Example with table Data, which is the same...

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        *
FROM Data  tM
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Data t WHERE tM.Source = t.Dest AND tM.Dest = t.Source AND tm.Source > t.Source)
```

or (*Nice and Access Formatted...*)

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Data AS tM
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT 1 FROM Data t WHERE tM.Source = t.Dest AND tM.Dest = t.Source AND tm.Source > t.Source))=False));
```

Comment: First revision returns 1,2; 1,2; 3,1  which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: I just run this on MS Access and it returned 1,2 3,1. Did you test this? Did you include the **DISTINCT** ?

Comment: Astander, copied it one-to-one, just replaced Table1 with Data

Comment: Astander mine is Access 2003, SP3

Comment: Please check your query properties that *Unique Values* is set to **Yes**.

Comment: Astander, I guess that's * since I have columns other than Source and Dest. Specifying Source and Dest next to DISTINCT fixes it.

Comment: Yes, that would be it. DISTINCT works on an entire row/selected fields.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate duplicates, "select distinct" is easier than "group by":

```
select distinct source,dest from data;
```

EDIT: I see now that you're trying to get unique *combinations* (don't include both 1,2 and 2,1). You can do that like:

```
select distinct source,dest from data
minus
select dest,source from data where source < dest
```

The "minus" flips the order around and eliminates cases where you already have a match; the "where source < dest" keeps you from removing both (1,2) and (2,1)

Comment: will return 1,2 ; 2,1; 3;1 - 2,1 should be excluded

Comment: You can't use minus in MS Access, hence the problems :)

Answer (score 0):

your question is asked incorrectly. "unique combinations" are all of your records. but i think you mean one line per each Source. so it is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tab t1
WHERE  t1.Dest IN 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 DISTINCT t2.Dest
   FROM tab t2
   WHERE t1.Source = t2.Source
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work in MS Access 2003, complains about IN clause. Btw, just in case there is a sample of desired output in the question to eliminate possible ambiguity.

Comment: this query will return desired rows, but i have no idea how to write in in ms access sql.

Comment: Andrey, apologies, I clarified within the question that it's got to be Access 2003.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM
(SELECT
  LEAST(Source, Dest) AS min_val,
  GREATEST(Source, Dest) AS max_val
FROM table_name) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.min_val, t1.max_val
```

Will return

```
1, 2
1, 3
```

in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Use this query :

```
SELECT distinct *  from tabval ;
```