# How to find unique pairs from two columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a table"Dummy" with columns "col1 and col2".

How do i find unique pairs from(col1,col2). For example in the above table how do i get (a,b) or (b,a) only as my output, instead of both (a,b) and (b,a).

```
select
    distinct
    col1
    col2
from
    dummy
where
    dummy.col1 < dummy.col2
group by
    col1,
    col2;
```

the above query is wrong as it missed out the pair (d,c).

[image: Wrong query]

Comment: I think you want `WHERE col1 <> col2`, not `WHERE col1 < col2`.

Comment: Do you need get the existing `d,c` or is `c,d` ok, too?

Comment: @Dai you get both `a, d` and `d, a` in that case.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. *You could have just googled your title.* Always google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code & 'stackoverflow' and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch unique combinations of two field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386632/fetch-unique-combinations-of-two-field-values)

Answer (score 3):

i would rather use concat and group by

```
SELECT 
col1,col2 
FROM 
tbl
GROUP BY CONCAT(LEAST(col1, col2), 
              GREATEST(col1, col2))
```

OR SIMPLY

```
SELECT 
    col1,col2 
    FROM 
    tbl
group by LEAST(col1, col2),GREATEST(col1, col2)
```

Comment: Of course this only works in MySQL and will fail in other DBMSes or when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care if an existing combination is returned in the right order, e.g. `a,b` might also be returned as`b,a`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN col1 > col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 end, -- similar to LEAST
  CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 end  -- similar to GREATEST
FROM dummy
;
```

But if you must return an existing row it' more complicated:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM dummy AS t1 LEFT JOIN dummy AS t2
ON  t1.col1 = t2.col2
AND t1.col2 = t2.col1
AND t1.col1 > t2.col1
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
;

SELECT col1,col2
FROM dummy AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM dummy t2
  WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col2
    AND t1.col2 = t2.col1
    AND t1.col1 > t2.col1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    x,
    y
FROM
(

    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        col1 AS x,
        col2 AS y
    FROM
        dummy
    WHERE
        col1 <> col2

    UNION

    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        col1 AS y,
        col2 AS x
    FROM
        dummy
    WHERE
        col1 <> col2
)
```

Comment: Why the outer Select and why two DISTINCTs when UNION is distinct anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Use `least` and `greatest`.

```
select least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2) 
from tbl
group by least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2)
```

But this may return rows that aren't in the table if only one pair of (x,y) or (y,x) exists.

To avoid that, use

```
select least(col1,col2) as col1,greatest(col1,col2) as col2
from tbl
group by least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2) 
having count(*)>1
union all
select col1,col2 
from tbl
where (least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2)) in (select least(col1,col2) as col1,greatest(col1,col2) as col2
                                                 from tbl
                                                 group by least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2) 
                                                 having count(*)=1
                                                )
```