# Select unique pair of string regarless of the order

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have an sql table composed of unique pair of strings:

```sql
Table: 
("a","b")
("a","c")
("a","d")
("b","a")
("d","a")
```

How can I select the unique element regardless of the order and produce th following output:

```
Output: 
("a","b")
("a","c")
("a","d")
```

i.e. unique pair

Comment: See least and greatest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938232/how-to-find-unique-pairs-from-two-columns-in-sql

Comment: Are they two separate columns?

Comment: yes it does TY all !