# Get inverted value with single function in TERADATA

Tags: function, teradata

Can you guys help me go through this:

```
Input: 
First_Name    Last_Name
John          Smith
Smith         John

Output:
Customer_Name
John Smith
John Smith
```

So basically, what I want here is to get the Customer Name as sometimes the First & Last name are inverted in the database and I would like to do it in TERADATA using just a function (of possible of course) without using UNION/UNION ALL for example.

Comment: How do you know what's first and last name?

Comment: I don't. What I'm doing is concatenate the first and last name to get the "customer name" and then I'm checking for similarity. I'm doing it using the same SELECT twice with UNION.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938398/2527905

Comment: I just used "Least & Greatest" functions and it gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a little alphabetical comparison between the two columns and take the min and the max in any case
Example:

```
select 'John' as a ,'Smith' as b ,case when a > b then a else b end Less_
    ,case when a <= b then a else b end More_
```

Regards,

Comment: This will get a **consistent** result, but not necessarily a **correct** result.  There is no way to look at a pair of names and tell which is which.

Comment: @Andrew How would you do that as a human being with any level of accuracy?